# Reverse ArrayList on link

Tags: java, jsp, arraylist, reverse

I have an ArrayList which consist of custom made objects called "History". When I click a link, the one called "Deposit1" at the top of my code example, I display the list in correct order.

However, I want to be able to reverse the list when the user click on the link "Deposit2" inside the table which is only displayed after the users click on the first link, "Deposit1".

Right now nothing happends, but I can system.out.print succesfully on secound link click.

Is there anyway to do this?

Note that code example is trimmed for better overview.

```
ArrayList <history> history = historyDAO.getHistory(x, y);



<li>
     <a href="history.jsp?Dep1=valueOfDep">Deposit1</a>
</li>

String sortDep1 = request.getParameter("Dep1"); 
String sortDep2 = request.getParameter("Dep2");

if (sortDep1 != null) {         
    
    <table class="table text">
      <tr>
        <th>Result</th>
        <th>Sport</th>
        <th>Deposit2<a href="history.jsp?Dep2=valueOfDep">Deposit2</a></th>
      </tr>

 if (sortDep2 != null) {
    Collections.reverse(history);
   }   


for (int i = 0; i < history.size() && i < list1.size(); i++) {
     
    <tr>
            <td><%=history.get(i).getRes()%></td>
            <td><%=history.get(i).getSport() %></td>
            <td><%=history.get(i).getDeposit()%></td>
    </tr>
  
<%}}%>

</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: if-sortDep2 is nested in if-sortDep1 so will never be called as the links either set Dep1 or Dep2.

Comment: Yes excactly my problem. If I nest the if-sortDep2 outside it will "reset" my page, and dont display the data from if-sortDep1. So, I will have to make alot of redundans otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass `2` parameters in your href tag for both `Dept1` & `Dept2` so that `sortDep1` is not null and it will go inside `if-statement` and depending on the value which is in url you can reverse your list. i.e :

```
if (sortDep1 != null) {         
<table class="table text">
<tr>
   <th>Result</th>
   <th>Sport</th>
   //pass 2 parameter in url for dep1 & dep2
   <th>Deposit2<a href="history.jsp?Dep1=valueOfDep&Dep2=reverse">Deposit2</a></th>
</tr>
//check if not null and value is reverse
  if ((sortDep2 != null) && (sortDep2.equals("reverse")) {
    Collections.reverse(history);
    }   
 //other codes
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the first `if-sortDep1` to:

```
if (sortDep1 != null || sortDep2 != null) {
```

then that part of code is always entered when either is valid.

Comment: I have tried that. It works, but it will display the list twice becurse the list is called both on sortDep1 first, and afterwards when the second link shows and is clicked. I want to reverse the list back and forth when sortDep2 is clicked - sortDep2 is only showed after the list is already showed.